# Can I use Gwibber to access LinkedIn?

Tags: gwibber, social

I installed Ubuntu for the first time a couple of days ago so I'm just getting set up. I'm not a big social media user but I do use FB and Linked in a bit. Gwibber seems to work for FB but not for LinkedIn. Is there a way I can configure something to make it work or is there an alternate client I should be looking at?
Thanks

Martin

Comment: Wow. Very good question indeed.

Answer (score 1):

## Not with the official client

> ## ***Danger!*** This is a delicate procedure and the code is not finalized. Make a backup before doing this.

There is not "official" LinkedIn support for Gwibber, but there is a third party solution. However, it requires removing the old Gwibber files, which can be dangerous. Also, it is not finalized, but in development, so it may have bugs.

Get the branch, and install:

```
sudo apt-get install bzr
md gwibber-linkedin   
cd gwibber-linkedin
bzr branch lp:~andrewsteinborn/gwibber/linkedin-support
sudo setup.py
```